# Show that $\cos(\omega t)$ can fit any random set of data points for sufficiently high $\omega$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I was reading through the paper ['Dos and don'ts of reduced chi-squared'](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.3754.pdf), and in section 2.4 they make the following claim:

> Let us consider the following model $f(x)$, having three free parameters $A,B,C$,
>   $$f(x)=A\cos(Bx+C).$$
>   If we are given a set of $N$ measurements $(x_n,y_n,\sigma_n)$ such that no two data points have identical $x_n$, then the model $f(x)$ is capable of fitting any such data set perfectly.

In the above, $y_n$ are measured values corresponding to $x_n$, with Gaussian error $\sigma_n$. We judge the fit of a model in the sense of the reduced chi-squared, i.e. minimising the normalised error

$$\chi^2_{red}=\frac{1}{N-3}\sum_{n=1}^N\left(\frac{y_n-f(x_n)}{\sigma_n}\right)^2,$$

where the $3$ comes from the fact there are three parameters in the model.

I had a play with this in Mathematica. I generated 50 data points uniformly distributed in the region $(-1,1)\times(-1,1)$, and found that these could be fit with the parameters $(A,B,C)=(1,1081670,0)$ with a $\chi^2_{red}=1.000001$, which is an almost perfect fit ($1$ is the ideal value).

My question is, what approach can I use to prove that this can always be done for any set of finite data points? They key would be to show that given any set of $(x,y)$ points in the region $(-1,1)\times(-1,1)$ (with no $x$-values repeated), we can find an $\omega$ that minimises $|y_n-\cos(\omega x_n)|$ below any required threshold, but I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to prove?  That any error tolerance specified at the outset can always be met by a suitable sinusoid?

Comment: Yes, that would be sufficient.

Comment: I think you need some sort of dense set argument, but don't have time to work it out.